# Ads API - Custom Audiences - Error Code #U8i8

Tags: error-code, facebook-ads-api

We had a client using the Ads API to upload a batch of phone numbers for Custom Audiences who received the error code #U8i8 without any additional information. Cluster ID was 6006341262522. We also saw the error a while back during initial development and believe it might be somewhat transient even against the same file. Any hints on what this means?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your audience is empty, possibly because of malformed phone numbers.  Have you normalized your phone numbers before uploading?

- Normalize the phone number by removing any symbols, letters, and any leading zeroes.
- Prefix the phone number by country code.  E.g., add '1' for a US phone number.